# RecyclewView with nested gridView adjust height

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to create this view:

[image]

It´s `Rerecyclew` with a `Gridview` for each item.
So when you press the plus item I've to add a new item to the `Gridview` and adjust the `RecyclewView` item height.

But i can't make it with a `wrap_content` and i don´t know why.

**Activity Layout**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_scenes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**RecyclewView Item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gv_scene_items"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:columnWidth="50dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#eaeaea" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**GridView Item (just for example)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:background="@color/liloColorBlue">



</LinearLayout>
```

Can you help me to get the example view?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution creating my own gridview like this:

```
public class ScenesGridView  extends GridView {

        public ScenesGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public ScenesGridView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public ScenesGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2,
                    MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
        }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very easily. 
Change the recyclerView height in xml to:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_scenes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

This will automatically adjust the layouts.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` or `notifyItemChanged(int position)` methods of the `RecyclerView.Adapter` from the MAIN THREAD.

I hope this can help you